# Vector Calculus - Curve trajectory question

Tags: calculus, vectors

Quote;

"Now suppose we have a scalar function $f(\mathbf{r})$ and we want to consider the rate of change along a path $\mathbf{r}(u)$. A change $\delta u$ produces a change $\delta \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}' \delta u + o(\delta u)$, and
$$
  \delta f = \nabla f\cdot \delta \mathbf{r} + o(|\delta \mathbf{r}|) = \nabla f\cdot \mathbf{r}'(u)\delta u + o(\delta u).
$$
This shows that $f$ is differentiable as a function of $u$ "

1) Looking at

$\delta \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}' \delta u + o(\delta u)$

How can we have vector = vector + scalar?

2) When we substitute in $\delta \mathbf{r}$, how do we get to the final result (i.e can someone expand the last equation to show workings in full and reasoning for each step)

Answer (score 0):

1) Looking at

$\delta \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}' \delta u + o(\delta u)$

How can we have vector = vector + scalar?

A1) Read this not as vector + scalar, rather that the $o(\delta u)$ is a small vector. So rather read: vector + vector.

2) When we substitute in $\delta \mathbf{r}$, how do we get to the final result (i.e can someone expand the last equation to show workings in full and reasoning for each step)

A2) What have you tried? Where are you at in your investigation?

Comment: I have tried direct substitution, my problem comes from dealing with the little o notation and simplifying it to the desired $o(\delta u)$

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be differentiable? Think on this. In this case it falls out immediately.

Comment: In relation to A1, we know that $u$ is a scalar so therefore $\delta u$ is also a scalar so how can we then make the leap to assume $o(\delta u)$ is a vector?  - And thanks, will see if I can get anywhere with that

Comment: Assuming that $o(\delta u)$ in the context of the equation is the only thing that makes sense. In words we would say that $\delta \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}' \delta u + o(\delta u)$ MEANS: a small change in the path parameter gives a small change in the displacement vector that is first order linear in that change.\ You write $o$ notation to leave out small details that don't matter here. It is only to show the general sense of the effect.

Comment: Okay, thanks! In terms of $f$ being differentiable, is this not what we are trying to prove? (Also, it's that a change in the parameter gives a first order change in the function)